# Why are there backup messages in my SQL Log when no scheduled backups are running?

Tags: sql-server

While troubleshooting a "while waiting for buffer latch -- type 4" timeout error I checked the SQL Log files and there are a TON of BACKUP DATABASE and success statements. There are no scheduled backups (including T-Logs) anywhere near the time of the message below. No maintenance plans either. I also scripted out all the jobs but didn't find anything.

```
04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,Database backed up. Database: EDS_Staging<c/> creation date(time): 2019/07/29(09:27:55)<c/> pages dumped: 386<c/> first LSN: 40508:1251:43<c/> last LSN: 40508:1271:1<c/> number of dump devices: 1<c/> device information: (FILE=1<c/> TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'{D0FDCDF5-6122-409F-83E2-9FE1EB231826}7'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 0 pages in 104.536 seconds (0.000 MB/sec).

04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 0 pages in 102.651 seconds (0.000 MB/sec).

04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 0 pages in 103.459 seconds (0.000 MB/sec).

04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,Database backed up. Database: PETS<c/> creation date(time): 2019/07/22(08:50:00)<c/> pages dumped: 18107<c/> first LSN: 167131:191:1<c/> last LSN: 167136:716:1<c/> number of dump devices: 1<c/> device information: (FILE=1<c/> TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'{D0FDCDF5-6122-409F-83E2-9FE1EB231826}6'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,Database backed up. Database: JTS<c/> creation date(time): 2019/06/05(07:48:59)<c/> pages dumped: 1536<c/> first LSN: 407:4725:1<c/> last LSN: 407:5488:1<c/> number of dump devices: 1<c/> device information: (FILE=1<c/> TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'{D0FDCDF5-6122-409F-83E2-9FE1EB231826}5'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

04/27/2021 05:04:15,Backup,Unknown,Database backed up. Database: ACR<c/> creation date(time): 2019/03/06(09:31:45)<c/> pages dumped: 709<c/> first LSN: 71:27659:1<c/> last LSN: 71:27862:1<c/> number of dump devices: 1<c/> device information: (FILE=1<c/> TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'{D0FDCDF5-6122-409F-83E2-9FE1EB231826}4'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Perhaps these are some sort of "system backups" (I'm not the man when it comes to reading the log). However because they are running at the same time as the task for which I'm getting the buffer latch type 4 errors I'd like to get them out of the way if possible.

Any help or insight would be most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Don't make any kind of change if you don't understand what it means. SQL Server backups don't prevent the database from running, even in SQL Server Express. It does that by using `tempdb` though, so if you underprovisioned `tempdb` eg put it on a slow disk or restricted its size, you'll get into trouble sooner or later. A *lot* of things in SQL Server use `tempdb`. It's also used if there's not enough RAM to hold temporary results

Comment: Did you google that error message? What database version are you using? There may be a bug like [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4089819-fix-a-time-out-occurred-while-waiting-for-buffer-latch-type-4-error-when-you-use-availability-groups-in-sql-server-2016-or-2017-232353f7-dcbc-3b80-45ad-3fc0cd546f95)

Comment: Using SQL server 2017. I'm in a situation where I have to troubleshoot and fix this buffer latch type 4 timeout even though I don't have the knowledge or experience. Additionally the only test I have is a 90 minute agent job and the error is intermittent so even a 90 minute test doesn't ensure that it's fixed. I've checked a lot of website articles and TempDB is mentioned a lot and so is a lot of other stuff I have no experience changing. I still have to account for those backup messages to my boss. Any idea where they are coming from?

Comment: I don't know what's going on on your system. I know you shouldn't try random things because they'll cause *far* worse problems. You found yourself that `tempdb` is involved. Why are you looking at the backup messages then?

Comment: You can try [sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) a *very* popular health-check script, to find out what may be wrong on your system. Even the quick-check results point to problem descriptions and possible fixes. Brent Ozar has published more health-check scripts, like [sp_BlitzFirst](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main#sp_blitzfirst-real-time-performance-advice) that tells you why the database is slow when it runs, eg running backups

Comment: Why am I looking at backup messages in the log? Because as far as I know they don't belong there. I'm not going to skip over it and say "oh it's probably fine". I also have zero leads to go on for the latch error so I was checking the log and I saw the backup messages. I get it if you don't address things you find in the process but if I skip things I get fired.

Comment: But as you said, you don't know. And what you've found until now points to tempdb. You do know that if you mess with backups you can cause damage and even lose data. Even if you find out what executes those backups (Windows Scheduled Tasks maybe? Some other scheduling engine? Some third-party backup tool?) *you won't have fixed the problem*. You'd only add the possibility of losing data.